# Input raw audio 512 floating-point values into FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, floating-point, actionscript

In ActionScript 3, I use [SoundMixer.computeSpectrum()](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()) to takes a snapshot of the current sound wave playing on the stage and places it into the specified ByteArray object.

I want to write the ByteArray into FFMPEG (by std -i pipe:0), but the ByteArray object created is fixed to 512 floating-point values and FFMPEG seem [doesn't support that value](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types). The sound in the output is corrupted.

Here's a part of my code in AS3:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    var soundBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(soundBA, false, 0);
    process.standardInput.writeBytes(soundBA);
}
```

Comment: You need to write out a succession of bytes per frame. So, no. of samples * sampling rate. Thats how the pipe input works, you write out data on per frame basis and you tell ffmpeg details of the data so it can be processed.

Comment: Do you know if "512 floating-point values" is the packet size, what is the "depth" of a sample? Is it 32-bit or 16-bit...? I can not find in the document.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()
And how to catch samples * sampling rate /a second in AS3 to adapt FFMPEG audio format?

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains using ffmpeg to process raw audio.

1. The user must be clear on the sample format of the audio. You have stated `512 floating-point values` - this is not indicative of a format. I assume it is `f32le`
2. All digital audio requires a sampling rate (usually 44.1khz or 48khz)
3. Num of Channels - whether stereo or mono.

When you specify the input for a pipe, these values are specified. So, for a floating point data type, the following input specs are valid -

```
 -y -f f32le -ar 48000 -ac 2 
 -y -f f32le -ar 48000 -ac 1 
 -y -f f32le -ar 44100 -ac 2
 -y -f f32le -ar 44100 -ac 1
```

Which one of these is yours ?

Based on this information, your command may be -

```
ffmpeg <format> <sampling rate> <num channels> -i <pipe name> -f wav output.wav
```

This could be -

```
ffmpeg -y -f f32le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i <pipe name> -f wav output.wav
```

pipename can be named pipe or using stdio (-i - or -i pipe:0)

More info here - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types